# Sum of symmetric matrices (one of which is rank one): how do eigenvectors behave?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $B$ a symmetric, semipositive definite matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.
Consider:

$$A:=a\otimes a+B$$

Besides the simple consideration that if $a$ is an eigenvector of $B$ everything is fine and very explicit, is there any way to:

1) compute eigenvectors for $A$ using the ones of $B$ and $a$?

2) compute eigenvalues for $A$? (this would be a concequence of (1)).

One can easily see that provided that $(w,\mu)$ is an eigencouple for $A$ then:

$$\langle a,w\rangle^2+ \langle w, Bw\rangle=\mu\lvert w\rvert^2,$$

and some other similar equalities (even coordinatewise), but I cannot really make them work.

EDIT: note that $a\otimes a$ and $B$ commute if and only if $a$ is an eigenvector for $B$, thus these matrices cannot be, in general, simultaneulsy diagonalized.